# Do modules finally allow readable names in the standard library implementation?

Tags: c++, c++20

With the introduction of modules in C++20 we finally have a tool to encapsulate code from one another. Especially because the preprocessor macros don't leak to other modules.

Afaik, the reserved names (like `_Tp`, `_First`, `__last`) were introduced to avoid macros messing up the standard library implementation, for example:

```
#define first Yabba Dabba Doo

template <typename RanIt>
std::sort(RanIt first, RanIt last);
```

I'm aware that the standard library won't be modularized for C++20, but probably for C++2x. Would a modularized implementation of the standard library finally allow normal, readable names for things like parameters and internal types (without running into UB or compiler errors) or is there some other restriction blocking this?

Comment: @Timo I am not entirely sure here, but I guess the placeholder for the next standard iteration would be `c++2b`, not `c++2x`, given that the one for C++20 was commonly `c++2a`.

Comment: @walnut isn't it `x`, `y`, `z`? I thought `a` was just used because there are probably 4 iterations in this decade.

Comment: @walnut [They're pretty much just calling it C++23](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0592r4.html) at this point. The whole "we'll do it at some point" thing is something the committee really wants to get away from. But it remains to be seen what the compiler switches end up being...

Comment: ([The great unwashed do seem to be calling it C++2b though](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support))

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Yeah, I don't think the compiler developers have thought about it yet, but cppreference [already uses `C++2b`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#cpp2b).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a standard library implementation specifically for a module-based interface would be isolated from user-defined macros and therefore could use "normal" names. Well, maybe; I'll cover that possibility at the end.

Regardless, I would not expect this to happen in the immediate future, even after a hypothetical C++23 with libraries in modules.

The reason being that you would still need to be able to `#include` the standard headers, even in module-based code. So those headers need to still be available. And while a compiler could legally convert `#include <vector>` directly into `import std.vector` (assuming both define the same things), it may be a backwards compatibility break for users of that platform who might add some `#define`s before the `#include`. There would be no similar expectations if you `import std.vector`.

Given that you'll still need the standard library headers lying around, it's highly unlikely that any implementation will want to support 2 copies of standard library code: one for headers and one for modules. It's must easier to define the standard library modules by `#include` the appropriate headers and `export` specific symbols from them.

So the base code would still be written as headers and therefore would still have to assume that users could have any set of `#define`s before the `#include`.

There is one issue that could make this impossible. Modules still have to deal with external defines, not from user code before a `#include`, but from compiler switches. People will use such switches to parameterize their modules, and that's fine. However, such switches are outside of the domain of the standard, so it's not clear whether implementations would have to code defensively against them or not.

Comment: I'd expect the `vector` header to become one line in the medium term `import std.vector;`.  So `#include <vector>` isn't translated *by the compiler*, but instead by the implementation of `std`.  I guess they cannot do this as long as "turn off modules" compiler option is supported without two sets of `<vector>` headers.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: And as I said, if you've been relying on doing some `#define <implementation-specific-macro> #include <vector>` in order to cause some special thing to happen in that `<vector>` include, then that wouldn't be possible. It's a backwards compatibility issue.